# carry over factor in beam ( moment distribution )

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

In the solution , we notice that the 2823.6 is the result of carry over factor from BA to AB . Why we dont need to do the same thing for BC to CB ? [image: dd]
[image: dd]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it is an end pin joint, it is assumed that no moment can occur in the joint.

The Moment carried from BA to AB because AB is a fixed joint, and thus incur a moment as a result of the moment at joint B.

Check out the [Moment Distribution Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_distribution_method) Wikipedia page and look at their worked example, it should help clear things up.